# php-fpm and CPU Overutilization on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: apache-2.2, php-fpm, ubuntu-16.04, central-processing-unit

I've got configured apache2 and php7.2-fpm. 
Machine has 32 vCPUs and 192G ram. 
FPM is set to static mode with 1200 pm.max_children. 
When 400 fpm process are started the platform is slow and load average on system peak up to 230 and meanwhile CPU max is 40%. I think that something is not configured correctly

EDIT:
After I made the following changes:
pm.max_children = 64 the platform is handling better(~40% load average constantly and ~40%CPU usage) but with 2500 users in GA it's slowing down. I still think that there is config issue. 
Apache rate of request show this:
[Apache requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iGbR5.png)

While fpm shown such graphic: [FPM requests](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eABW3.png)

What do you think could be the issue?

Comment: Please post at minimum your fpm and apache configs, as well as a sample of your diagnostic tools (`top`, `ps`, `iotop` etc) output.

Comment: Hello, my config were:
php fpm mode : static
pm.max_children: 1200
Apache config is:
ServerLimit 32
StartServers 20
MinSpareThreads 512
MaxSpareThreads 2048 
ThreadLimit 128
ThreadsPerChild 64
MaxRequestWorkers 2048
MaxConnectionsPerChild 50000

Comment: PHP can be very CPU intensive. PHP with Wordpress can take 25 - 75% of a CPU core, which assuming 75% means with 32 cores you can have about 40 processes running at the same time without slowing down. 400 processes means each gets 10% of a core, which isn't much. I suggest you consider caching, if appropriate, which can massive reduce CPU usage, otherwise you may need to add more CPU resource - scaling horizontally is typically the easiest way.

Comment: Some caching information [here](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/tutorials/hosting-wordpress-on-aws-tutorial-part-4-wordpress-website-optimization/) about Nginx, just as an example - I wrote it so I have the link to hand. With Wordpress I can cache all pages requests from users who aren't logged in, so my server is barely loaded.

Comment: We are talking about Laravel, not WP. We use CDN and Redis a lot. I think we'll need to scale horizontally really.